# Advantages Of MySQLi over MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What are the advantages of using MySQLi over MySQL?

Comment: You should consider PDO instead, since the plan is to "make PDO the primary supported DB interface".  http://wiki.php.net/summits/pdmnotesmay09

Answer (score 32, accepted):

See [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php):

> **What is PHP's mysqli Extension?**
>
> The mysqli extension, or as it is
> sometimes known, the MySQL improved
> extension, was developed to take
> advantage of new features found in
> MySQL systems versions 4.1.3 and
> newer. The mysqli extension is
> included with PHP versions 5 and
> later.
>
> The mysqli extension has a number of
> benefits, the key enhancements over
> the mysql extension being:
>
> - Object-oriented interface
> - Support for Prepared Statements
> - Support for Multiple Statements
> - Support for Transactions
> - Enhanced debugging capabilities

Comment: You're playing with fire if you're not using prepared statements, you only need to get hacked a couple of times to realize that!

Comment: @Ali: a *couple* of times?

Comment: @Dominic, what do you mean by support for transactions? We can do transactions with basic mysql too right?