# Does PDO implements mysqli or mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PDO and I got this message, but from what I found I thought PDO actually implemented mysqli.

> You are using PHP's deprecated 'mysql' extension, which is not capable
>   of handling multi queries. **The execution of some stored routines
>   may fail!** Please use the improved 'mysqli' extension to avoid any
>   problems.

Why do I get this message, then?

Comment: yes mysql_* api is deprecated you have to use new api for connecting to database like pdo or mysqli

Comment: @ArunKillu So if I use pdo there is no need for mysqli right?

Comment: Yeah. `PDO` implements `mysqli` instead of `mysql`. Just check out a latest version.

Comment: I suppose it would be useful to get more detail of the PDO version and if other thing in your setup could be connecting without PDO.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost like asking what's the difference between `DOMDocument` and `SimpleXML` or what's the difference between `php` and `python`.  They're different libraries, although they're both for interfacing with a MySQL database server.

PHP has done [quite a nice job of cataloging the differences](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Answer (score 1):

**Mysql** doesn't support for running multiple queries at a time. **Mysql** also doesn't support for prepared statement. Because of that you have to use **Mysqli**, it supports both.

Comment: `php_mysql` doesn't support stored procedures as well.

Comment: @user2308038 Install `mysqli` extension on your server and use this tutorial http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of discussion on this topic previously. You better search on the Internet (Even only in the Stackoverflow).

Like:

[What is difference between mysql,mysqli and pdo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190737/what-is-difference-between-mysql-mysqli-and-pdo)

[Difference between mysqli and mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641752/difference-between-mysqli-and-mysql)

You need to do more research man. Think critically and be a programmer. ;)

Comment: I was not asking the difference between them. I was asking why using PDO prompted that message since from what I found PDO actually implemented mysqli.

Comment: then, first link would be better for you.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought PDO actually implemented mysqli.

Nice question but false though.
PDO implements the interface so that you can use all Database System. So, it just can't implement some features from `mysqli` as they require some special features that are not yet emulated for SQLite for example ! You can find similar issues when you compare PDO and `pgsql_` API.