# MySQL new library and notepad++

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, notepad++

As I understand it, the normal mysql `mysql.*` method library has been superseded somewhat by the library `mysqli.*`. Essentially, my understanding is that the new library uses all the old methods just with the letter "i" tagged onto the end of the method name. Three questions:

1. Why have MySQL updated this library and what new features does it contain?
2. For users of Notepad++, the language of choice can be selected from a drop-down menu, which then highlights the code much like an IDE does, for instance methods are coloured blue and are in bold font. When I first wrote some MySQL code, I used the old library methods, not being aware of the advancement. When I converted it to the new library methods, the blue/bold highlighting disappeared and returned to normal font. When I deleted the "i" in the method name, it became highlighted again. Why does Notepad++ not recognize the new methods?
3. Are the new methods a requirement (i.e. Will the old methods still work in PHP)?

Comment: MySQLi is not different from MySQL. Here's the usual message we usually give to people using `mysql_*`: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/14112684/285587

Answer (score 13):

Using Notepad++, highlight mysqli, then

1. open note pad select settings
2. select style configurator
3. in language select php
4. in style select WORD
5. in user-defined key words enter the keyword you want highlighted.
   make sure there is a space after false (first item.)
   Below is a list (It's the ones I use.)
6. Save and close.

True false
mysqli_affected_rows
mysqli_autocommit
mysqli_change_user
mysqli_character_set_name
mysqli_close
mysqli_commit
mysqli_connect_errno
mysqli_connect_error
mysqli_connect
mysqli_data_seek
mysqli_debug
mysqli_dump_debug_info
mysqli_errno
mysqli_error_list
mysqli_error
mysqli_fetch_all
mysqli_fetch_array
mysqli_fetch_assoc
mysqli_fetch_field_direct
mysqli_fetch_field
mysqli_fetch_fields
mysqli_fetch_lengths
mysqli_fetch_object
mysqli_fetch_row
mysqli_field_count
mysqli_field_seek
mysqli_field_tell
mysqli_free_result
mysqli_get_charset
mysqli_get_client_info
mysqli_get_client_stats
mysqli_get_client_version
mysqli_get_connection_stats
mysqli_get_host_info
mysqli_get_proto_info
mysqli_get_server_info
mysqli_get_server_version
mysqli_info
mysqli_init
mysqli_insert_id
mysql_kill
mysqli_more_results
mysqli_multi_query
mysqli_next_result
mysqli_num_fields
mysqli_num_rows
mysqli_options
mysqli_ping
mysqli_prepare
mysqli_query
mysqli_real_connect
mysqli_real_escape_string
mysqli_real_query
mysqli_reap_async_query
mysqli_refresh
mysqli_rollback
mysqli_select_db
mysqli_set_charset
mysqli_set_local_infile_default
mysqli_set_local_infile_handler
mysqli_sqlstate
mysqli_ssl_set
mysqli_stat
mysqli_stmt_init
mysqli_store_result
mysqli_thread_id
mysqli_thread_safe
mysqli_use_result
mysqli_warning_count

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer number 1 for you because I don't know the details.

2:  I don't know why it's not included by default, but you can add it manually.
Go to settings->style configurator and choose php under language.    Choose WORD under style.
In the box called "User-defined keywords"  Add all the mysqli_* functions you use.  They'll be highlighted from now on.

3:  For now, they will work.  It was deprecated in 5.5, which means it will throw a warning when you use it.  Eventually, it will be completely removed.  Still, switch over to mysqli so nothing breaks when you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

From PHP.net's FAQ about [databases](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated)

> **Why is the MySQL extension (ext/mysql) that I've been using for over 10 years discouraged from use? Is it deprecated? What do I use
>   instead? How can I migrate?**
>
> There are three MySQL extensions, as described under the [Choosing a
>   MySQL API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) section. The old API should not be used, and one day it
>   will be deprecated and eventually removed from PHP. It is a popular
>   extension so this will be a slow process, but you are strongly
>   encouraged to write all new code with either [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or
>   [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).
>
> Migration scripts are not available at this time, although the mysqli
>   API contains both a procedural and OOP API, with the procedural
>   version being similar to ext/mysql.
>
> It is not possible to mix the extensions. So, for example, passing a
>   `mysqli` connection to `PDO_MySQL` or `ext/mysql` will not work.

---

As to your question regarding Notepad++ features, you'll have to ask it on their official forums/community.

---

Your 3rd question's reply is hidden in the excerpt above:

The old API **should not be used**, and one day it will be *deprecated* and *eventually removed* from PHP. It is a popular extension so *this will be a slow process*, but you are **strongly encouraged** to **write** all **new code** with either [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Answer (score 0):

> Essentially, my understanding is that the new library uses all the old methods just with the letter "i" tagged onto the end of the method name.

Not necessarily. `mysqli` functions are now in two forms, either procedural (like old `mysql` ones) or object-oriented style. (e.g. `$result->fetch_array()`).

From [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php)

> The mysqli extension features a dual interface. It supports the procedural and object-oriented programming paradigm.

Some of the new `mysqli` functions also accept different arguments from the old ones. Most generally, most of the functions now require a `mysqli` link (the `mysqli` connection) as their argument.

As for why they've changed it, it obviously must have a few reasons. The top ones being security and stability, and introducing the new OO-styles must be one reason.

Have a look at this for the benefits: [MySQLi extension benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171344/advantages-of-mysqli-over-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

1) According to [php.net's overview](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php)

- Object-oriented interface
- Support for Prepared Statements
- Support for Multiple Statements
- Support for Transactions
- Enhanced debugging capabilities
- Embedded server support

2) I've never used Notepad++, I use Sublime Text 2. Text editors may not cater to every language, so maybe there's a Notepad++ plugin for mysqli?

3) [The MySql overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) says:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future.

It might be a good idea to make the switch, it certainly wouldn't hurt and it would definitely be nice to stay up to date with the way PHP interacts with MySql.

---

Edit: For me writing MySqli is smoother than MySql because I don't have to include a connection at the end of a query when using the MySqli class.

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table");
```

Instead of

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table",$link);
```