# PHP Video upload not storing values in DB and in DIR

Tags: php, html, mysql

> This code has no error, checked the console no errors, print_r($temp) gives proper result.
>   print_r($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]) gives proper result but the values are no stored in the 
>   phpMyAdmin Db and in the uploaded_videos dir. The last line is also not printed on the screen

```
<?php
  include("database_connection.php");
  $allowedExtn = array("mp4","mov","avi","wmv","flv","mpeg");
  $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  $extension = end($temp);
  $videoname = $_FILES["file"]["name"];



  if((($_FILES["file"]["type"]=="video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"]=="video/mov")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"]=="video/avi")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"]=="video/wmv")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"]=="video/flv")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"]=="video/mpeg"))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExtn))
  {
 if($_FILES["files"]["error"]>0)
 {
    echo "Error in Uploading video ". $_FILES["file"]["name"];
}

else
{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploaded_videos/" . 
      $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $filepath = "uploaded_videos/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $query = "INSERT INTO video_upload (username, video_name, video_ext,          
            video_url) VALUES ('Venkat', 'videoname','$extension','$filepath')";
    mysql_query($query);
    print_r($query);
    mysql_close();
    echo "Video " .$videoname . " saved.";
}


  }

 ?>
```

> Can anyone please tell me where is the short coming..??

Comment: are you sure the uploaded_videos directory is writeable by your script?

Comment: how do i find that out.?? I mean I was able to store PDFs and Docs in a directory called upload_resume in a similar way.!

Comment: depending on the system you are working you might get directory permission information (either on a console/ftp/ssh/whatever client).

Comment: `echo mysql_error();` right after the query...

Comment: echo "Video " .$videoname . " saved."; is notworking $videoname is not getting printed, echo "hi" and echo echo mysql_error() showing no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on linux and have access to the filesystem then check the permissions and ownership of the uploaded_videos directory (use `ls -la` or similar) if you need to change them then look up `chmod` and `chown` or use your `cpanel`? interface.

- Make sure also that the directory exists where you think it does (in    the same directory as the script you are running).
- The first task to sort out is the writing to disk - I'd suggest    commenting out the mysql for now.
- Also try it with a small file that has a shortish filename with no    funny characters or spaces first.
- Turn on error reporting in your script error_reporting(E_ALL);    ini_set('display_errors',true)
- and check the return value of move_uploaded_file
- if it is false with no errors then check the file
- if it is false with errors then check the filesystem (and the errors)

Comment: hey @soqls, I am using Windows. yes the directory exists in my project folder in htdocs (where the index etc files are present).

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL); this is what i read to enable all error reporting but no error is shown.. :(

Comment: display_startup_errors=On and display_errors = On and  error_reporting(E_ALL);  no result

Comment: ok - try var_dumping $_FILES to see that all is in order (filesize not bigger than php.ini settings, named ok etc. try writing any file to that directory. try a 3 letter file extension as a test as well (make it as simple as possible to test). Check you've enough disk space. Also just for assurance run getcwd() to see what directory it thinks this script is in - and use that to ensure it's trying to write to file where you think it is.

Comment: array(1) 
{ ["file"]=> array(5)

 { ["name"]=> string(10) "video1.flv" 
   ["type"]=> string(24) "application/octet-stream" 
   ["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php6B96.tmp" 
   ["error"]=> int(0) 
   ["size"]=> int(9745167) } }

Comment: your file type is application/octet-stream and you're filtering on video/flv

Comment: if you're on php 5.3 + then try something like: $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME); echo $finfo->file($_FILE['file']['tmp_name']);

Comment: video/x-flv; charset=binary    This is the result, flv type that means.!!

Comment: ...thanks alot I was able to debug the things and find my way out...everything is working now and every video type is getting uploaded..Cheers..!!

Answer (score 1):

First of all use `MySQLI` or `PDO` for your queries.

```
 $insertQuery = " INSERT INTO `databaseName`.`tableName` (`username`,`video_name`,`video_ext`, `video_url`) VALUES ('Venkat','videoname','$extension','$filepath') ";

 $insertQueryResult = $connector->query($insertQuery);
```

I think you should put the

`$filepath = 'uploaded_videos/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];`

below of the :

`$videoname = $_FILES['file']['name'];`

This is just a simple sample for using `MySQLI`. You can refer to [THIS LINK](http://www.php.net)

Comment: mysql and my_sqli, big diff..??

Comment: Refer to this for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171344/advantages-of-mysqli-over-mysql