# Data from MySQL changing from no data into zero

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table of "score" in my database

```html
!  id   !  A   ! 
-----------------
!  01   !  10  !  
!  02   !      !  
!  03   !      !  
!  04   !  5   !
```

```
$mySql = "SELECT score.id, score.A 
          FROM score
          ORDER BY score.id ASC"; 
$myQry = mysql_query($mySql, $koneksidb)  or die ("Query salah : ".mysql_error());
    while ($myData = mysql_fetch_array($myQry)) {
        $id=$myData['id'];
        $A=$myData['A'];
 }
```

When I call with

```html
<?php echo $A; ?>
```

It came out with zero instead of no data,

```html
!  id   !  A   ! 
-----------------
!  01   !  10  !  
!  02   !  0   !  
!  03   !  0   !  
!  04   !  5   !
```

What should I change?

Comment: Remove all code snippets.

Comment: It's the second semester of 2016 and `mysql_*` is still being used. Oh god why have you forsaken us?

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: could you give me example how to change it into better one?

Comment: Please read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php If You still have a good reason to use mysql_* functions, describe it and retag question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if they are `null` values they will be echoed as `0`.

You can do this ternary hack:

```
<?php echo ($A==0)?' ':$A; ?>
```

I didn't test, but I believe it will work. Maybe you could do that, also:

```
<?php echo (isset($A))?$A:' '; ?>
```

Also, [quit using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171344/advantages-of-mysqli-over-mysql), please!

Comment: @gtviga if it works you should mark this answer as accepted. Green tick near the voting buttons

Answer (score 0):

That's all right. Simplify,

```
$any_empty_var == false == 0
```

So, you can just add the condition

```
if ($A == 0) echo " ";
else echo $A;
```

Answer (score 0):

!.) You should use mysqli as mysql is obsolete.
2.) set score.A so that it can simple diplay null values

ALTER TABLE `score` CHANGE `A` INT(11) NULL;
the mysql will return a  null value